# Paypal IPN and wordpress failure

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a website that i will be accepting paypal IPN's from paypal. This site is a wordpress website, on a shared enviroment, that i have customized. Using the IPN simulator it always fails on my webservice listener for ipn but succeeds for the base url.  Why can i not receive a success on my webservice and log the data?

Using my browser and hitting the below webservice will write my logfile. Using IPN simulator never writes to my logfile. Also my SSL access logs never receive a POST from IPN but http does. Access log at bottom

Hitting

https://example.example.org/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/controllers/payments/ipn

Fails for IPN simulator.**"IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information."**

Hitting
https://example.example.org/

Succeeds in hitting **IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.**

```
 Core::error("In the ipn function");
            // STEP 1: read POST data
            // Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
            // Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.
            $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
            $myPost = array();
            foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
              $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
              if (count($keyval) == 2)
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
            Core::error("IPN");
            Core::error(json_encode($myPost));
            Core::error(json_encode($_GET));
            Core::error(json_encode($_POST));
            // read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
            $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
            if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
              $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
            }
            foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
              if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
              } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
              }
              $req .= "&$key=$value";
            }

            $path = "/home1/xx/";
            $cert = "ff67367c5cd4de4ae18bcce1d70fdabd7c866135.pem";


            $sandBoxUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            $prUrl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            // Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
            $ch = curl_init($sandBoxUrl);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $path . $cert);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
            // In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
            // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set
            // the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/home1/xxx/cacert.pem');
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            if ( !$res ) {
              Core::error(curl_error($ch));
              // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
              curl_close($ch);
              exit;
            }
            Core::error("Resposne");
            Core::error($res);

            curl_close($ch);

            // inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                    Core::error("VERIFIED ");
                    // The IPN is verified, process it

                    // The IPN is verified, process it:
                    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
                    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
                    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
                    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
                    // process the notification
                    // assign posted variables to local variables
                    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
                    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
                    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
                    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
                    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
                    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
                    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
                    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
                    // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
                    // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
                    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                            $data =  $key . " = " . $value . "<br>";
                            Core::error($data);
                    }

            } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
                    Core::error("invalid ");
            }

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    die();
```

HTTPS Log After IPN Spammed

```
 ip - - [14/Jun/2016:19:29:05 -0500] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "https://wordpress.example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=example%2Fexample.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
ip - - [14/Jun/2016:19:30:07 -0500] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "https://wordpress.example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=example%2Fexample.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
ip - - [14/Jun/2016:19:31:07 -0500] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "https://wordpress.example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=example%2Fexample.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
```

NonHttps Log After IPN Spammed

```
ip - - [14/Jun/2016:17:35:13 -0500] "POST /wp-content/plugins/example/controllers/payments/ipn HTTP/1.1" 406 275 "-" "-"
ip - - [14/Jun/2016:17:37:10 -0500] "POST /wp-content/plugins/example/controllers/payments/ipn HTTP/1.1" 406 275 "-" "-"
ip - - [14/Jun/2016:17:39:04 -0500] "POST /wp-content/plugins/example/controllers/payments/ipn HTTP/1.1" 406 275 "-" "-"
ip - - [14/Jun/2016:17:58:28 -0500] "POST /wp-content/plugins/example/controllers/payments/ipn HTTP/1.1" 406 275 "-" "-"
ip - - [14/Jun/2016:17:58:35 -0500] "POST /wp-content/plugins/example/controllers/payments/ipn HTTP/1.1" 406 275 "-" "-"
```

**edit** If i replace my script with [this](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) and place it in the root directory of my site it will work. It i move the script to anywhere under the root dir it will not work.

**edit2** Using my script or not the IPN always succeeds on the index of my site. I dont understand why it would succeed here

Comment: Hitting

https://example.example.org/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/controllers/payments/ipn <---what if you include the file extension at the end?

Comment: I still get "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information." So far it only seems to work on the root of my site. Anywhere else and i get a failure.

Comment: try putting the github scrpit in the same directory as your wordpress one (the one that you tested fine when placed in the root directory) and test if you get a verified handshake when you point to IPN simulator to it. This is to check if the issue is server/certificate configuration related or script related.

Comment: Tried running the new script from my original location and i wasnt able to get it to work. But i still get a valid response when hitting the root of my site. :(

Comment: but you can access your IPN script using the https:// protocol in your browser right? If so it is most likely a server config problem, which I think you can get better help solving if you edit your question title accordingly.

Comment: Yes i can hit my script in my browser. Also it seems that even when i run the IPN simulator and it says successfully my script does not log anything even when my logging is the first code to be executed. Only when i actually hit the page with my browser does my script log. I agree i just have no idea what the acutal problem would be so i dont know what to change the title to.

Comment: check with your host the version of SSL/TLS it supports and are you sure curl is enabled?

Comment: I checked with my host and the only thing out of date was curl but it was still working correctly. The issue was that sending IPN request from developer.paypal.com is actually like their PR. Apparently i need to send request from sandbox.paypal.com... Thanks for your help though

Comment: if you can't get the handshake to verify with an IPN simulator, I very much doubt you will get it working with sandbox. IPN simulator uses sandbox, technologically speaking they are the same, it is just a quick test tool before one constructs more complex testing in sandbox with dummy accounts and credit cards info etc.

Comment: Hope it all works out for you though, good luck =)

Comment: Correct, but in the paypal example code you can switch from sandbox to pr. My curl was always set to send back to sandbox and i was getting messages from developer. I have not tested this yet but i assume if i switch from sandbox.paypal.com to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and use the IPN simulator at developer.paypal.com i would get a verified handshake. I will test this out later and report back.

Comment: hmm...... from my experience if you point the return address to the live site when the data is sent from sandbox (inc. IPN simulator) you will get an IPN sent and handshake verified message on screen (that's given your script is in proper working order), but the cmd-validate parameter would return as invalid therefore shows in your log as INVALID.

Comment: If your script is pointing to the right corresponding address, be it sandbox or the live site at the time it was triggered but the script only works with the live site not sandbox than the issue lies in SSL/TLS config of your server because sandbox only permits data transmission over SSL/TLS whereas the live site permits IPN message to be sent over the HTTP. Anyway do let me know when you found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that for development you need to send IPN requests from the IPN simulator at sandbox.paypal.com instead of developer.paypal.com.

You also must login to sandbox.paypal.com with your something-facilitator@example.com creds that were created in developer.paypal.com.